# RoR Passenger webserver "Extra File" errors on gem check --alien

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, passenger

I just installed the Phusion Passenger webserver via gem install. I then did a `gem check --alien` and got this error message:

```
fastthread-1.0.7 has 3 problems
  .require_paths:
    Extra file
  ext/fastthread/Makefile:
    Extra file
  lib/fastthread.rb:
    Extra file

passenger-2.2.15 has 5 problems
  .require_paths:
    Extra file
  ext/phusion_passenger/Makefile:
    Extra file
  ext/phusion_passenger/native_support.o:
    Extra file
  ext/phusion_passenger/native_support.so:
    Extra file
  lib/native_support.so:
    Extra file
```

googled it up to no avail...any fixes for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All those messages are completely normal. First, recall what 'gem check --alien' does according to its docs:

```
   -a, --alien                      Report 'unmanaged' or rogue files in the
                                    gem repository
```

Both Phusion Passenger and fastthread are gems that contain native extensions, i.e. C libraries that are compiled when you install those gems. The extra files that you see are the compilation output files. They should be there, otherwise those gems wouldn't work.